# Why is True + 2 , 3 or False + 2, 2

Tags: python, boolean

```
>>> True + 2
    3
>>> False + 2
    2
```

I can understand that somehow, True means 1 and False means 0 . So
does it mean, a Boolean and integer operation always gives an integer?

Comment: Yes. Adding a boolean to an int produces an int, because in Python `True==1` and `False==0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and therefor satisfies the ["is-a"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relation, meaning *a bool is-a int*.

To demonstrate:

```
issubclass(bool, int)
=> True
isinstance(True, int)
=> True
```

In practice this means that in any operation which works on an int, the int can be substituted with a bool.